# How to Logout the API when Application cleared from stack i.e when app goes to destroy state in android

Tags: android, session

I'm devloping banking application, i want to do autologout the application after 5 minutes when user is inactivity state and destroy the application.

I'm using timer for foreground service after 5 mintues it will come to login screen.

Without clicking logout option user is clear the application that means destroying the application.how autologout will work. Give me solution.

This code im calling in "onuserinteracted method in common activity"

```
public class MyApp1 extends Application {
    private LogOutListener1 listener;
    private Timer timer;
    private Context context;


    public void startUserSession(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        long sessiontime = Prefs.getsessiontime(ctx);
        final long milliseconds = sessiontime * 60000;
        cancelTimer();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    boolean foreGround = new ForegroundCheckTask().execute(context).get();
                    if (foreGround) {
                        listener.onSessionLogout();
                    } else {
                        long millis = new Date().getTime();
                        Prefs.setcurrenttimestamp(context, millis);
                    }


                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ignored) {

                }
            }

        }, milliseconds);
    }

    public void cancelTimer() {
        if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
    }

    public void registerSessionListener(LogOutListener1 listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void onUserInteracted() {
        startUserSession(context);
    }

    private static class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
            final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
            return isAppOnForeground(context);
        }

        private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            if (appProcesses == null) {
                return false;
            }
            final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
                if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Clear the user data if you are saving when the user is logging.

Comment: logout value should be update in database also,i want to call API when user directly destroying the application means.

Comment: you check for the application lifecycle to decide what to do when the user is destroying the application.

Comment: i'm calling this application class in activity so ondestroy method will call when application is killed ,in that place i'm calling the logout API but its not calling. Anyother way is there or not.Please suggest me

Comment: the way you are doing is also fine.

Comment: @siddhi , Actually there is no guaranty the onDestory() will call every time so maybe issue arise.

Comment: Yes, then how to achieve ,when user destroying the app,logout api need to call then only logout value will be update in database.

Comment: i want to logout the api when app is destroying how to do. I given for testing,they are checking in burp suite, first time they logged in  after 10 hrs they are trying to hit the same api its showing already logged in ie wrong right.because app is not loggedout when user cleared from recent app

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you

As per google new `LifecycleObserver` mechanism will help you

First, add this below tow  dependancy In Project your app
First, add in project-level `gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Then after in App-level `gradle`

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
```

Then after creating your application class and add bellow logic (Note: if you already created then modify and add below some methods)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {


    String strPrafKey = "bi_vrnfX";
    String strKeyTime = "timeKey";
    private String strKeyLogin = "is_login";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onAppBackgrounded() {
        //App in background

        //Store app goes in background time
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(strPrafKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long currentTimeInSecond = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
        sharedpreferences.edit().putLong(strKeyTime, currentTimeInSecond).apply();
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onAppForegrounded() {
        // App in foreground

        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(strPrafKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long lastBackgroundTime = sharedpreferences.getLong(strKeyTime, 0); //Take last background time for compare
        long currentTimeInSecond = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
        long timeDeffrance = (currentTimeInSecond - lastBackgroundTime) / 60; //Diffrance of last background and current time in minute
        if (timeDeffrance > 5) {
            sharedpreferences.edit().putBoolean(strKeyLogin, false).apply();
            //You can replace this code or data with which you are comparing in your login
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, if you have not registered this class in manifest then register to set name tag in your manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Comment: I want to call Logout API also,in database value should be change.

Comment: You can call logout API managing one flag if the app opens after erasing login which we did in onAppForegrounded here you can set more flag and handle in your splash login for call previous session logout may be.

Comment: that im doing only but that way is wrong right,it should be logout when application is destroyed automatically. In oreo version Service is not working properly,taskfromremoved method is not calling